# trouble with the error expected "end"

Tags: vbscript

what am I doing wrong in this script?

```
Randomize
value=int((150 * Rnd + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
guess+inputbox("guess the number","guess","guess here")
if guess=value then
  msgbox("correct"),0+64+4096,("guess")
  wscript.quit
else
  if guess < value then
    msgbox("too low"),0+32+4096,("guess")
    once=1
  end if
else
  msgbox("too high"),0+32+4096,("guess")
end if
once=1
do
  guess=inputbox("try again","guess","guess here")
  if guess=value then
    msgbox("correct"),0+64+4096,("guess")
  else
    if guess < value then
      msgbox("too low"),0+32+4096,("guess")
    end if
  else
    msgbox("too high"),0+32+4096,("guess")
  end if
loop
```

If you can figure out what is going wrong that would be great.

It has been saying

> expected "end"

and when I do what it says I will run it and it still won't work.

Comment: Do you mean to use `else if` rather than `else` a lot of the time.

Comment: Or perhaps the line under the `else` should be on same line as the `else` to turn it into an `else if`. Also `lowerbound` isn't defined so will be treated as 0.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`Select-Case`](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/vbscript_conditionals.asp) for faster and more readable code.

Comment: @PankajJaju Is `Select Case True` faster then `ElseIf`? That's debatable...

Comment: @Lankymart - According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t9x467f(v=vs.84).aspx), Case is more efficient. In my experience, I validate 10k test trade files and have found Case to be faster.

Comment: @PankajJaju That is true when you have something like `Select Case <specific condition>` but when you replace that with `Select Case True` like you would have to in this example, then you lose the efficiency. Which is personally why I think `ElseIf` fits this scenario better. Notice the last line of that link you posted - *"You can replace an `If...Then...ElseIf` structure with a `Select Case` structure **only if** each `ElseIf` statement evaluates the **same** expression."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have edited the code to properly indent it which should help highlight the issue. The error is because an `If` statement can only have one `Else` condition, the basic structure of an `If` statement is;

```
If <boolean condition> Then
  <true outcome>
Else
  <false outcome>
End If
```

At the moment you have multiple instances of

```
If <boolean condition> Then
  <true outcome>
Else
  <false outcome>
Else
  <unknown condition>
End If
```

which is invalid syntax because a *basic* `If` statement can only return `True` or `False`.

However there is also `ElseIf` which allows multiple boolean conditions to be specified and return different outcomes.

Which looks like this;

```
If <boolean condition> Then
  <true outcome>
ElseIf <boolean condition> Then
  <true outcome>
ElseIf <boolean condition> Then
  <true outcome>
Else
  <false outcome>
End If
```

Based on how you are nesting the `If` statements the code in question could be re-written like this;

```
Randomize
value = Int((150 * Rnd + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
guess = InputBox("guess the number", "guess", "guess here")

If guess = value Then
  Call MsgBox("correct", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "guess")
  WScript.Quit
ElseIf guess < value Then
  Call MsgBox("too low", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "guess")
  once = 1
Else
  Call MsgBox("too high", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "guess")
End if
once = 1
Do
  guess = InputBox("try again", "guess", "guess here")
  If guess = value Then
    Call MsgBox("correct", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "guess")
  ElseIf guess < value then
    Call MsgBox("too low", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "guess")
  Else
    Call MsgBox("too high", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "guess")
  End If
Loop
```

Couple of things to note about the example above

1. Replaced the `+` with `=` in the line

   ```
   guess+inputbox("guess the number","guess","guess here")
   ```

   as it won't assign the result of `InputBox()` to `guess` which is what I'm assuming you are doing. If you were trying to concatenate the result of `InputBox()` to `guess` that still wouldn't work you would have to use

   ```
   guess = guess + InputBox("guess the number", "guess", "guess here")
   ```

   If that was the case though personally I prefer to use `&` over `+` for string concatenation.
2. The brackets in `MsgBox()` appear to be a bit odd, usually you would call `MsgBox()` without brackets if not returning the result to a variable, like this;

   ```
   MsgBox "correct", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "guess"
   ```

   but if you did want to include the brackets *(as I prefer to do)* you can just use `Call` like this

   ```
   Call MsgBox("correct", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "guess")
   ```

   which avoids the dreaded

   > Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub

   but still allows the function to be surrounded with brackets when no value is being returned.
3. You may also noticed that I replaced the hardcoded numeric values in `MsgBox()` with the [Named Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1ft6yf3(v=vs.84).aspx) which is easier for others to read and interpret their meaning. They are also hard-boiled into VBScript so there is no excuse for not using them.

---

Thinking about what you trying to do thought I could re-factor the code a little bit to hopefully make it work as you expected

```
Dim value, guess, msg, once
Randomize
value = Int((150 * Rnd + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)

Do
  If once = 0 Then
    msg = "guess the number"
  Else
    msg = "try again"
  End If
  guess = CInt(InputBox(msg, "guess", "guess here"))
  If guess = value Then
    Call MsgBox("correct", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "guess")
    WScript.Quit
  ElseIf guess < value then
    Call MsgBox("too low", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "guess")
    once = 1
  Else
    Call MsgBox("too high", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "guess")
    once = 1
  End If
Loop
```

Things to take from this;

1. We only need the one `InputBox()` inside the loop to handle both the first initial guess and the subsequent "try again" attempts. This means we are not duplicating the same piece of code again, see [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
2. `InputBox()` returns a string so at first the code was trying to compare a string value with a integer value which will give all sorts of weird results. By casting to integer using `CInt()` the comparison starts to work as expected.